# App getting crash in background image loading iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, lazy-loading

I have scroll view with 60 `UIImageView's`. Images displaying in these imageviews are from url and url's i get from the webservice. When user scrolls to bottom I call the webservice and get **new 60 urls**. After getting the url i am utilizing same `UIImageView's` to display images. Following is my code for displaying images.

```
for (UIView *viewSel in [scrlView subviews]) {
    NSString *strImgUrl = [arrImgURL valueForKey:@"url"];
    if ([viewSel isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {

            UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)viewSel;

            [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading432x520.png"]];

            NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strImgUrl]];

            [arr addObject:imgView];
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) withObject:arr];

            [arr release];
    }
}


- (void) loadImageInBackground:(NSMutableArray *)arr  {

    NSLog(@"loadImage");
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arr objectAtIndex:0]]];
    UIImage *img    = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
    if (img != nil) {
        [arr addObject:img];
    }
    else{
        [arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image432x520.png"]];
    }
    [img release];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(assignImageToImageView:) withObject:arr waitUntilDone:YES];
    [pool release];
}
- (void) assignImageToImageView:(NSMutableArray *)arr{
    NSLog(@"assignImage");
    UIImageView *imgView = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
    imgView.image = [arr objectAtIndex:2];
}
```

The code works perfect for first time. But when i get new urls it is working some time or getting crash. I don't know why it is getting crash. I want to stop that crash. If you are not getting to my question then let me know. Please help me for this. Thanks in advance. Valid answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any log message while crashing?

Comment: no i didn't get any log message for crash.

Comment: Why are you doing this "UIImageView *imgView = [arr objectAtIndex:1];" while in that array you are adding "UIImage" instance not "UIImageView" instance

Comment: I'm bit confuse which array you are using to store url as a string again same array you are using to store "UIImage" instance.

Comment: start with enabling nszombie...you will get a log, and then you can figure out where the crash might be happening

Comment: Have you tried moving all UIKit code from your background thread ?

Comment: First time are you able to display 60 images?

Comment: Thanks to all for giving comments. Nikita P i have enabled nszombie and got the following error.    [CALayerArray countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x9cadd20     i have searched for this error and found that it is for allocating and deallocating the memory so i have removed nsautoreleasepool from the (loadImageInBackground:) but still it is crashing. do you have any idea why is it so ?

Comment: yes marcio i have moved all the uikit operation in main thread by this line of code [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(assignImageToImageView:) withObject:arr waitUntilDone:YES];  in (loadImageInBackground:) method.

Comment: yes rajneesh071 it is displaying 60 images for first time. But I am not waiting for displaying all the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all to give your help full comments to my question. I got the error. I am adding CALayer to uiimageview when allocating memory to uiimageview. I remove that CALayer code and it work perfectly. Nikita's comment help me to find my error.